# How to store changes in javascript object to revert them later with Vue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vue.js, watch

I have a todo app. The functional is simple: you can add a note with list of todos. You can later edit it on note edit page (add more todos). But I also need a feature to store "note" object changes in array to be able to revert them later.

**template:**

```
<form class="note">
      <h4>Edit Note <span v-if="note.title">"{{ note.title }}"</span></h4>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter note title"
        v-model.lazy="note.title"
      >
      <div class="createTodoWrapper">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add todo"
          v-model="todoTitle"
        >
        <button
          @click.prevent="addTodo"
          class="addTodoBtn"
        >+</button>
      </div>
      <ul
        class="todosList"
        v-if="note.todos"
      >
        <h4>Todos:</h4>
        <li
          v-for="todo in note.todos"
          :key="todo.id"
        >
          <p>{{ todo.title }}</p>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            v-model="todo.completed"
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p v-else>No todos yet</p>
      <div class="buttonsWrapper">
        <button @click.prevent="saveChanges">Save</button>
        <button @click.prevent="revertChanges">Revert</button>
        <button @click.prevent="redoChanges">Redo</button>
        <button
          @click.prevent="showModalDelete = true"
          class="deleteBtn"
        >Delete</button>
        <button @click.prevent="showCancelEditModal = !showCancelEditModal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**note looks like that:**

```
{"id":"1723d1fffa7","title":"Test","todos":[{"title":"first","id":"1723d83bbe7","completed":false},{"title":"second","id":"1723d83cca7","completed":false}]}
```

**And here's some logic:**

```
// I detect changes and put newVal in an array
watch: {
    note: {
      handler: function(val) {
        if(val) {
          let item = this.cloneNote(val)
          this.noteHistory.push(item)
          console.log('newVal')
        }
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },

revertChanges() {
      if (this.counter <= this.noteHistory.length) {
        this.counter ++
        this.note = this.noteHistory[this.noteHistory.length - this.counter]
      }
    },
```

But as I revert changes then watcher triggers again and my history of changes array grows!

How can I avoid this?

Comment: You can dynamicly add en remove watches: https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/adding-removing-watchers-dynamically, else you could use a method with an `on:change` event instead of a watch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first idea that comes to mind is having an `isUndoing` property that short circuits history updates.

```
data() {
  return {
    isUndoing: false
  }
},

methods: {
  revertChanges() {
    this.isUndoing = true
    // existing code
    this.isUndoing = false
  }
},

watch: {
  note: {
    handler: function(val) {
      if(val && !this.isUndoing) {
        // existing code
      }
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

If you want to make it more generically-named for the Redo case as well, it could be `isManipulatingHistory`.